# Looping an object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I'm having a problem with looping an object in Swift.
I want to declare the UITextfield as an instance variable so I can access it anywhere inside the class.

So if I put it **inside the loop** it works fine, but I put the variable of UITextField **outside the loop**, it doesn't show the first textfield in the view and the username textfield would be missing.

Here's my code

```
var placeHolderArr:[String] = ["Username", "Password"]

let loginField = UITextField() // <----- this one

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoHolder = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2))
    logoHolder.backgroundColor = self.utils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ff8f00")

    for index in 0...1 {

        let height = index * 60
        // When I declare the textfield variable in this line, it works fine.

        loginField.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: Int((logoHolder.frame.maxY + 30) + CGFloat(height)), width: Int(self.view.frame.width - 80), height: 50)
        loginField.placeholder = placeHolderArr [index]
        loginField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        loginField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        loginField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        loginField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        loginField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        loginField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        loginField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        loginField.center.x = self.view.center.x
        loginField.delegate = self
        loginField.tag = index
        innerY = Int(loginField.frame.maxY)

        print("index\(index)" )

        self.view.addSubview(loginField)
    }

}
```

Please see the screenshot below

Textfield when declared **inside** the loop: 
[image]

Textfield when declared **outside** the loop:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you use the same UITextField. Judt put initialization inside the loop

```
    for index in 0...1 {

        let height = index * 60
        // When I declare the textfield variable in this line, it works fine.

      loginField = UITextField() 
  loginField.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: Int((logoHolder.frame.maxY + 30) + CGFloat(height)), width: Int(self.view.frame.width - 80), height: 50)
        loginField
```

And to use it later use array:
var fieldArr:[UITextField] = []

Then later:

fieldArr.append(loginField)

Summarise:

```
var placeHolderArr:[String] = ["Username", "Password"]

let loginFields:[UITextField] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoHolder = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2))
    logoHolder.backgroundColor = self.utils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ff8f00")

    for index in 0...1 {
let loginField = UITextField()
        let height = index * 60
        // When I declare the textfield variable in this line, it works fine.

        loginField.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: Int((logoHolder.frame.maxY + 30) + CGFloat(height)), width: Int(self.view.frame.width - 80), height: 50)
        loginField.placeholder = placeHolderArr [index]
        loginField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        loginField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        loginField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        loginField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        loginField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        loginField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        loginField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        loginField.center.x = self.view.center.x
        loginField.delegate = self
        loginField.tag = index
        innerY = Int(loginField.frame.maxY)

        print("index\(index)" )

        self.view.addSubview(loginField)

loginFields.append(loginField)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the `UITextfield` subclass outside your loop, than every time when you set it up, you set up the same `UITextfield` instance. This means, you are overriding the first set of properties with the next one, every time you iterate on it.

Instead, lets create two instances, and set up both independently:

```
// declare this outside your loop
let usernameField = UITextField()
let passwordField = UITextField()

for (index, loginField) in [usernameField, passwordField].enumerated() { 
    // do your setup
}
```

Comment: better: `for (index, textField) in [usernameField, passwordField].enumerated() {...`

Comment: @Alexander everybody has his preference ;)

Comment: More than just a preference, it's shorter and avoids manually managing the index :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two properties:

```
let usernameField = UITextField()
let passwordField = UITextField()
```

and loop every text field like:

```
for (index, loginField) in [usernameField, passwordField].enumerated() {
    //do what you need
}
```